# Excel: Summing a row with text values in that correspond to numbers elsewhere

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In excel I have a series of rows with various letters in which correspond to a "key" which assigns each letter a value, I want to sum the row with the letters in, but need it first to look up the corresponding numerical value in the key then sum the row

[image]

I want to total the row in column F but for the formula to first look up the value corresponding to the letter in the key.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XLOOKUP to get the value of each key, then sum the values for each of the columns:

```
=SUM(XLOOKUP($A$1:$E$1,$I$2:$I$5,$J$2:$J$5,0))
```

[image]